# Checking if a file is corrupted on Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, pdf

Please, I need some help from you guys. I am developing a Phonegap application for Android that downloads some PDF files on a file explorer style interface and them open the files on the Adobe Reader application. The app works well on success scenarios, but if for some reason the connection drops during the download and you close and reopen the application, when you click the pdf file's icon, he tries to open the file - I cache the files on the internal storage, I only download if the file doesn't exists - and adobe reader shows a error of corrupted file. Is there a way on Cordova that I can check if a file is corrupted, so I can download it again if it is corrupted?

thank you

Comment: You can keep a MD5 hash of a file on server and then compare local hash with remote hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to keep a flag for each of the files you download to indicate that the download has completed? Once the file finished downloading you set a flag for that file. That way if a transfer is interrupted then the flag won't be set and you can treat that case as if the file doesn't exist so that your application doesn't try to open an incomplete file.

Comment: Or download to a temp location, then *move* the file to its permanent location only when the download is complete.

Comment: Great idea Jon! will do that! Thank you for all your answers, people!